# Vimeo Embed: Custom Play Button working. How to add a pause button?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, vimeo, vimeo-api

I managed to play a vimeo video with an external play button with this code

```
<div class="myvimeo_container">

<iframe id="vimeovid1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/vimeoID" width="854" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
<br>
<button onclick="play_video()">MY_PLAY_BUTTON</button>

<script>
function play_video() {
  var player = document.getElementById("vimeovid1");
  var data = { method: "play" };
  player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), "*");
}
</script></div>
```

This is working!

But I'm having trouble to add a second button for pausing the video.
Is there a way to implement a second

```
<button onclick="pause_video()">MY_PAUSE_BUTTON</button>

<script>
function play_video() {
  var player = document.getElementById("vimeovid1");
  var data = { method: "pause" };
  player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), "*");
}
</script>
```

I can't figure this out yet. I just started learning coding and it would be awesome if someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm using the code above in wordpress by the way... to embed a vimeo video... their responsive embedding is not so awesome... so I'm trying to work around a little bit...

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your function name to `pause_video`, since that's what your button is trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a simple case that you haven't named your physical function correctly for the pause button.

```
<button onclick="pause_video()">MY_PAUSE_BUTTON</button>

<script>
function pause_video() { //EDIT: Needed to call the function 'pause_video' to link up to your button
  var player = document.getElementById("vimeovid1");
  var data = { method: "pause" };
  player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), "*");
}
</script>
```

If you are looking at making your content more responsive, a really easy way is to do this with bootstrap, take a look at [this tutorial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/).

You'll end up with something like this which handles the fluid videos for you:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe id="vimeovid1" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/vimeoID" width="854" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>
```

If you don't want to use bootstrap then I've used the site [embedresponsively.com](https://embedresponsively.com/) in the past which prints out your embed in a neat little package something like this:

```
<style>
.embed-container { 
   position: relative; 
   padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
   height: 0; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   max-width: 100%; 
} 
.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100%; 
}
</style>

<div class='embed-container'>
   <iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/vimeoID' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
```